# Hands up animation when stand on a brick [ROBLOX]

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I need a script that can do an animation when you are standing on a brick. I just don't know how to do the animation. I can't find a free model with the animation I am looking for. Here is a preview of how I want the hands up. [PREVIEW OF THE ANIMATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k8bm.png)

The brick you are standing on is

```
script.Parent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways of animation; The newer [Animations](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Animation) and the older [Joints](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Joints).

The [guide](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Animations) should be able to help you to getting started with animations. It even got a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOYnY30x7FQ).

If you want to use a old style Joint animation, something like this might work:

```
local Block = script.Parent

local function MakeFakeShoulder(Character, Side)
    local Controller = { ["Stop"] = function() end }

    local Torso = Character:findFirstChild("Torso")
    local Arm = Character:findFirstChild(Side .. " Arm")

    if not Torso or not Arm then return Controller end

    local Shoulder = Torso:findFirstChild(Side .. " Shoulder")
    if Shoulder then
        local FakeShoulder = Instance.new("ManualWeld")
        FakeShoulder.Name = "Fake " .. Side .. " Shoulder"
        FakeShoulder.C0 = CFrame.new(1.5 * (Side == "Right" and 1 or -1),0.5,0)
        FakeShoulder.C1 = CFrame.new(0,0.5,0) * CFrame.fromAxisAngle(Vector3.FromAxis(Enum.Axis.Z), math.rad(-180))
        FakeShoulder.Part0 = Torso
        FakeShoulder.Part1 = Arm
        FakeShoulder.Parent = Torso

        Shoulder.Parent = nil

        function Controller:Stop()
            Shoulder.Parent = Torso
            FakeShoulder:Destroy()
        end
    end
    return Controller
end

local function MakeFakeShoulders(Character)
    local Controller = { }

    local Right = MakeFakeShoulder(Character, "Right")
    local Left = MakeFakeShoulder(Character, "Left")

    function Controller:Stop()
        Right:Stop()
        Left:Stop()
    end

    return Controller
end

local function GetHumanoid(Part)
    if Part.Parent == nil then return nil end
    return Part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
end

local CurrentlyTouching = { }
Block.Touched:connect(function(Part)
    local Humanoid = GetHumanoid(Part)
    if not Humanoid then return end

    CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] = CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] or 0
    CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] = CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] + 1
    if CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] > 1 then return end

    local Controller = MakeFakeShoulders(Part.Parent)   

    while CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] > 0 do
        if GetHumanoid(Block.TouchEnded:wait()) == Humanoid then
            CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] = CurrentlyTouching[Humanoid] - 1
        end
    end

    Controller:Stop()
end)
```

Note that if the ending touch do not register good enough, make a invisible `CanCollide = false` bounding part that is bigger than the visual part and put the script in that one instead,